# Python and web development | Mako - a lot of questions

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, web-deployment, mako

Not coming from an MVC background, but just working with php purely, one of the greatest challenges was to grasp frameworks and the MVC ideology. While I am sure many adhere to MCV as the standard way to push code, I lack finding basic introductions into frameworks, and while they also do seem quite tedious to get started with, my goal is purely to write some Python code into html documents.

At first glance Mako seemed as the solution to the problem, allowing me to write the Python code into html, but at second glance it seemed to require more work than just "that".

What I simply cannot find an answer to anywhere I have looked is the whole aspect of "how-to-start with Mako".

Looking at the Mako site this comes up:

```
<%inherit file="base.html"/>
<%
rows = [[v for v in range(0,10)] for row in range(0,10)]
%>
<table>
% for row in rows:
    ${makerow(row)}
% endfor
</table>

<%def name="makerow(row)">
<tr>
% for name in row:
    <td>${name}</td>\
% endfor
</tr>
</%def>
```

Once again I see the entire templating ideology (yuk) coming up, but I just want to write Python code into my html, period. So some questions that I have are:

- Once Mako is installed can I start putting Python code into HTML and it will work?
- If not, then I assume I need to put the example code from above into a .py file and put base.html in the same directory? Or do I put the .py file somewhere else?
- Will this work like CSS in the sense that I inside the html file include a similar fashioned call to the .py file (or .mako file or whatever its called).
- Since it sounds framework'ish, will I need to put the html file and the .py/.mako in the same directory or will they also have to be separated?
- EDIT: I may as well ask if I can then call my extensions .psp (even though its not mod_python).

I know many would say that this is stupid and that there are better ways of doing it and that I make a big mistake. But clearly there are no noob tutorials explaining this in finer
details, thus leaving to do it the way I see fit, ie. put Python code inside a file and be done with it.

I also looked on this mod_python, but since it seems as an old solution I would actually like to skip that one. However, I hope there is a "new" solution to embed Python into HTML.

PS. I know all the framework evangelists will jump me, but the intention is not debate how to write code. Since no noob/step-by-step tutorial can be found on either Pythons, Djangos 
or Makos website and for that matter Pylons, Pyramid etc. it must therefore be assumed that anyone wanting to do this knows their framework implementation methods by heart. But I dont, so I just want to put Python code into HTML and not spend/waste time on learning something that Python already should solve perfectly in the first place.

PPS. By noob, I mean I would love to know the basics such as. Take this code and put into this type of file and put that file there. Then take this file and do that. I just could not find this what so ever anywhere. Its like a public secret.....

Comment: Are you sure you have taken a look at the Django tutorial? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Please dont' as *a lot* of questions in one question. The purpose of this site is to ask *one question* per post.

Answer (score 2):

First, understand that unlike PHP - which is a custom developed language exclusively for *web development*, Python is a general purpose programming language. Using Python you can develop Windows apps, Mac apps, server side scripts, mobile applications, servers, network clients - everything and anything that a general programming allows you do to. Just like Java or C#.

Therefore, there are multiple ways to do web development in Python. Thinking "PHP is web development" is wrong, and thinking "Python web development will be like PHP web development", is also wrong.

Finally, keep in mind that since PHP was designed solely for web development, it "hides" a lot of the sundry details that go into writing code that needs to sit behind a web server and process requests and return responses in a strict format.

To do web development in Python, you first and foremost need to learn Python. This is different than PHP. You learn web development as you learn PHP (since that's its prime purpose). Once you learn Python, you can develop all sorts of applications; and many Python developers don't develop for the web.

> Since no noob/step-by-step tutorial can be found on either Pythons,
>   Djangos or Makos website and for that matter Pylons, Pyramid etc. it
>   must therefore be assumed that anyone wanting to do this knows their
>   framework implementation methods by heart.

Mako is a template language (like Smarty). It would be pointless to use it "standalone", just like Smarty is useless without PHP behind it.

All web frameworks have beginner's guides. Some are better than others. Django has one of the best documentation of any. Start [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/#first-steps). To use any of the frameworks, you would need to know the methods they expose. Just like you need to know the `mysql_*` methods of PHP to interact with MySQL.

The rest of your questions stem from the fact that Python is not like PHP; and hence what you have come to expect from PHP you didn't find in the Python ecosystem.

Comment: I have been working with Python for quite some time now, and I wanted to move into web development and use the "power" of Python for that.

Are you saying there is no way at all to code Python directly into web? Or at least some very very light weight solution. Thus why I mention Mako. 

Personally I want to stay far away from Django and its super complex infrastructure.

Comment: Use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org)

Comment: Flask is a framework, what I am looking for is embedded Python, no MVC, no framework, no middle man.

Comment: [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface#Example_application)